# How to bind ComboBox from ArrayList Values in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image]

But Not fill properly

i have also mention such table and code into image

code Like :

```
        DataTable dtUserType = new Common().GetUserType(true);
        DataTable dtUserType 1= new Common().GetUserTypeByUser(true);

        ArrayList lstUserTypeId =new ArrayList();
        lstUserTypeId.AddRange(dtUserType1.Rows[0]["UserTypeId"].ToString().Split(','));

        DataTable dtDownlist = new DataTable();
        dtDownlist.Columns.Add("UserTypeId");
        dtDownlist.Columns.Add("UserType");
        DataRow dr;


        foreach (string s in lstUserTypeId)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dtUserType.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                dr = dtDownlist.NewRow();
                 //List Of superior List
                if(s.ToString() != dtUserType.Rows[i]["UserTypeId"].ToString())
                {


                    dr["USerType"] = dtUserType.Rows[i]["UserType"].ToString();
                    dr["UserTypeId"] = dtUserType.Rows[i]["UserTypeId"].ToString();
                    dtDownlist.Rows.Add(dr);
                }


            }
        }


        cmbUser.DataSource = dtDownlist; 
        cmbUser.DataTextField = "UserType";
        cmbUser.DataValueField = "UserTypeId";
        cmbUser.DataBind();
```

Comment: Post your code, not a screenshot of your code and please explain clearly what the problem is.

Comment: Problem is that combo box fill multiple time and not proper UserTypeId. I want to fill UserType list which userTable have UserTypeId. means if UserType = B then combo Box fill C and D from ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

in general:

1. don't split a main table to sub tables with 1 column for each - that is why there are columns for in a table
2. when querying data - use LINQ
3. dont use DataTable when possible - observer how many casting operations i posted in my answer (in you case use the typed table Common)

   ```
   DataTable common = new Common(); // Id, UserType, UserTypeId

   var sections = common.Where(c => c.UserType.ToString() == "B").First()
                        .ToString().Split(',');

   DataTable dtDownlist = new DataTable();
   dtDownlist.Columns.Add("UserTypeId");
   dtDownlist.Columns.Add("UserType");
   DataRow dr;


   foreach (string id in sections)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < dtUserType.Rows.Count; i++)
       {
           if(Convert.ToInt16(id) == Convert.ToInt16(common.Rows[i]["Id"]))
           {
               dr = dtDownlist.NewRow();

               dr["USerType"] = dtUserType.Rows[i]["UserType"].ToString();
               dr["UserTypeId"] = dtUserType.Rows[i]["UserTypeId"].ToString();
               dtDownlist.Rows.Add(dr);
           }
       }
   }


   cmbUser.DataSource = dtDownlist; 
   cmbUser.DataTextField = "UserType";
   cmbUser.DataValueField = "UserTypeId";
   cmbUser.DataBind();
   ```